How to launch a different browser in global-setup.ts according to the current project without extra environment variable
How can I launch Chrome or Firefox according to the current project in global-setup.ts?
see the code about projects in my playwright.config.ts
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        browserName: 'chromium'
      },
      timeout: 400 * 1000
    },
    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
      },
      timeout: 400 * 1000
    }
  ]

in my global-setup.ts, I want to launch Firefox to login when I run the test using npx playwright test --project=firefox, and launch Chrome instead when the tests are run with npx playwright test --project=chromium.
I tried to set up an environment variable before starting test, something like set BROWSER=firefox, and check process.env.BROWSER to launch different browser in global-setup.ts, it works, but I guess Playwright could have built-in feature to support such case without defining extra environment variable.

Any particular reason not to just add these as custom scripts in your package.json? (I'm assuming you have one since this is a .ts file)

@agoff, yes the script could be export BROWSER=firefox && npm run test, but I'm just curious is there any builtin feature to do so
